# Simple parse query for one to many relationship

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

My question is a simple one. Can anyone please guide me how can I perform the following query using `parse api` efficiently.

`delete from tablename where colA in ('1','2','3')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (not tested) :

```
var query = new Parse.Query("ObjectName");
query.containedIn('colA',['1','2','3']);
query.find().then(function(results) {
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
}).then(function() {
    response.success();
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error.message);
});
```

Comment: Good answer.  Response success/error is only for the end of a cloud function.